# How to get a TypeScript project to run as a child process in a JavaScript project?

Tags: javascript, typescript, express, electron, tsconfig

I have an electron app which is mainly all in javascript, I also have an express server project which is written in typescript, if I try to make a child process of this typescript project in my electron.js file I get typescript errors that my server.js doesn't understand the .ts filetype it's trying to import (they exist, it just doesn't know how to handle them). `TypeError [ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION]: Unknown file extension ".ts"`

==== Electron App ===

Here is my package.json in the electron app:

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "react-app-rewired build",
    "start": "react-app-rewired start",
    "electron": "electron ."
}
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2020",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true
  },
  "include": ["src", "expressproject/src"]
}
```

This is how I'm trying to run the express project in my electron.js:

// electron.js

```
const { spawn } = require("child_process");

// start express server
const expressServerProcess = spawn("node", [pathToServerJS]); // D:/expressproject/src/server.js

function createWindow() {
...
}
```

==== Express Project ====

Here is my package.json in the typescript express project

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "tsc -p tsconfig.json",
    "start": "npm run build && node --loader ts-node/esm --experimental-specifier-resolution=node server.js",
}
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "extends": "ts-node/node16/tsconfig.json",
  "ts-node": {
    "transpileOnly": true,
    "esm": true,
    "compilerOptions": {
      "outDir": "dist"
    }
  },
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "dist",
    "target": "ESNext",
    "module": "ES2020",
    "lib": ["ES2020", "ES2021"],
    "removeComments": true,
    "strict": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "noUncheckedIndexedAccess": true,
    "noImplicitOverride": true,
    "noPropertyAccessFromIndexSignature": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "stripInternal": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "allowUnusedLabels": false,
    "allowUnreachableCode": false,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "strictFunctionTypes": true,
    "strictBindCallApply": true,
    "strictPropertyInitialization": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "useUnknownInCatchVariables": true,
    "alwaysStrict": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true
  }
}
```

What I think is happening is the TypeScript code is not being transpiled to JavaScript? How can I do that?

Comment: `spawn("node"`   indeed, node knows nothing of Typescript, did you mean to call `ts-node`?

Comment: @Keith if I use ts-node there I get an Uncaught Exception: Error: spawn ts-node ENOENT

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-node   Make sure you have it installed,.

Comment: @Keith they are installed, same issue, however - I managed to get further I need to basically pass all the values I use in npm start on the typescript project as the commands I run in the child_process in the electron app. node --loader ts-node/esm --experimental-specifier-resolution=node server.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer with help from Keith:

Basically pass all the values (except the build script) I use in npm start script on the typescript project as the commands I run in the child_process in the electron app.

typescript express server package.json:

`node --loader ts-node/esm --experimental-specifier-resolution=node server.js`

electron.js

```
function startExpressServer() {
  const command = "node";
  const args = [
    "--loader",
    "ts-node/esm",
    "--experimental-specifier-resolution=node",
    pathToExpressServerJS, // expressproject/src/server.js
  ];

  const expressProcess = spawn(command, args, {
    shell: true,
    stdio: "ignore", 
  });

  expressProcess.on("close", (code) => {
    console.log(`Express server process exited with code ${code}`);
  });
}

startExpressServer()

function createWindow() {
...
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: worked for me for node 20, instead of downgrading to 19, thanks